# Memory Leak using sqlite

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, sqlite

I am getting a memory leak warning on Instruments for these lines:

```
 NSString *name =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

 year = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```

Here is the code for this section:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)selectUsersList:(NSString *)condition:(NSString *)sort
{
    NSMutableArray *users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      sqlite3_close(database);
      NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }
    else 
    {
      NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM users";
      if (condition != nil)
      {
        NSString *newQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", query, condition];
        query = newQuery;
      }
      if (sort != nil) {
        NSString *newsort = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", query, sort];
        query = newsort;
      }
      sqlite3_stmt *statement;

      if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
      {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *name =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            }
            NSString *year= @"";
            if (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2) != nil)
            {
                year = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            }

            User *user = [[User alloc] initWithName:name year:year];

            [users addObject:user]; 
            [user release];             
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
  }
  return users;
}
```

I want to present an empty string and not 'nil' on the view so I am setting year to an empty string first. Is there a better way to do this? How can I solve this leak?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `@""` does not leak. It's not the cause of your problem, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting a leak?

Comment: See my answer. Looks like you're leaking `statement`.

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB instead](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 6):

After the while loop, you must clear the sqlite3 statement's memory with `sqlite3_finalize()`. So:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *name =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

        NSString *year= @"";
        if (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1) != nil) {
            year = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        }

        User *user = [[User alloc] initWithName:name year:year];
        [users addObject:user]; 
        [user release];   
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement); // DO THIS
}
```

Comment: I am using sqlite3_finalize(statement); but it's still getting leak warning. Should I use sqlite3_reset(statement); as well?

Comment: You should not need to. What's the exact warning you're seeing?

Comment: It says leak object is User, multiple address and I'm also getting another leak at User class in this line: 
self.first = [self.name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

Comment: If your scope for `user` is as it is in the code you posted, it's a false positive--the object is correctly memory-managed. As for `-substringWithRange:`, it returns an autoreleased object so it will not leak, nor will a synthesized property setter. When do you create the `users` array, and when do you destroy it?

Comment: I just updated my issue description, check it out. I have the full method with the creation of users array. I am destroying it on the view.

Comment: As far as the analyzer can tell, you're leaking the array. Because the method name does not start with `create`, `copy`, `alloc`, or `new`, its semantics indicate the array should be autoreleased. So either rename your method something like `-(NSMutableArray *)copyUsersList:(NSString *)condition:(NSString *)sort` or modify your code such that the function's return value is autoreleased and the caller retains it as needed.

Comment: The leak is gone :) I changed the name of the method and it worked. Thanks so much for letting me know about this! I have another leak for this line:  
pdfView = [[TiledPDFView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect andScale:pdfZoomScale];
Any idea what can cause it here?

Comment: Ask a new question for that one and show some more code. Comments are not the right place for it. And if my answer has helped you, please click the checkmark beside it to "accept" it, because I am a sucker for +15 reputation.